# calculating distribution of $U=-\ln Y$

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be random sample of continuous distribution with distribution function $F$ if $$Y=\prod_{i=1}^k F(X_i) \prod_{i=k+1}^n [1-F(X_i)]$$ how can I calculate distribution of $U=-\ln Y$

Comment: I assume this is homework. Here are some hints. 1. show that the distribution of $F(X_i)$ (or $1-F(X_i)$...) is uniform on $[0,1]$. 2. What is the distribution of $-2 \log U$ where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ (the results is well known)? 3. Conclude.